# Implementing FIFO using LIFO

Tags: algorithm, fifo

Looking at some algorithm exercices on the net, I found an interesting one :

How would you implement a FIFO using a LIFO ?

I tried myself but I ended up with only one solution : each time we want the **front** element of the FIFO, copy the lifo into another lifo (**excluding** last element, which is the front), get the front element and remove it, then copy back the second LIFO into the first LIFO.

But this is of course horribly slow, it makes a simple loop like this :

```
for(!myfifo.empty()) {
  myfifo.pop();
}
```

going **O(n²)** instead of **O(n)** on a standard implementation of the FIFO.

Of course, LIFO are not made to do FIFO and we won't certainly have the same complexity by using a "native" FIFO and a fake-FIFO based on a LIFO, but I think there is certainly a way of doing better than O(n²). Has anyone an idea about that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906050/how-can-i-use-two-stackslifo-so-that-it-can-work-like-a-queuefifo

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a queue with three stacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538192/how-to-implement-a-queue-with-three-stacks)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get [amortized time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) of `O(1)` per OP FIFO [queue] using 2 LIFOs [stacks].

Assume you have `stack1`, `stack2`:

```
insert(e):
   stack1.push(e)

take():
   if (stack2.empty()):
      while (stack1.empty() == false):
            stack2.push(stack1.pop())
   return stack2.pop() //assume stack2.pop() handles empty stack already
```

**example:**

```
push(1)

|1|  | |
|-|  |-|

push(2)
|2|  | |
|1|  | |
|-|  |-|

pop()
push 2 to stack2 and pop it from stack1:
|1|  |2|
|-|  |-|
push 1 to stack2 and pop it from stack2:
| |  |1|
| |  |2|
|-|  |-|
pop1 from stack2 and return it:
| |  |2|
|-|  |-|
```

To get real `O(1)` [not amortized], it is much more complicated and requires more stacks, have a look at some of the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538192/how-to-implement-a-queue-with-three-stacks)

**EDIT:** Complexity analysis:

1. each `insert()` is trivaially `O(1)` [just pushing it to `stack1`]
2. Note that each element is `push()`ed and `pop()`ed at most twice, once from `stack1` and once from `stack2`. Since there is no more ops then these, for `n` elements, we have at most `2n` `push()`s and `2n` `pop()`s, which gives us at most `4n * O(1)` complexity [since both `pop()` and `push()` are `O(1)`], which is `O(n)` - and we get amortized time of: `O(1) * 4n / n = O(1)`

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the answer in fact. I did not think about the fact that until you have popped the FIFO until a given depth you won't have to worry about what is going IN the FIFO... Thanks a lot. And I'll look at the link about more than 2 stacks.

Comment: Well, I had already understand before the you edited your post, but now, it is a kind of royal answer, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Undo: You are welcome, I also added some short complexity analysis to show that these solution is indeed `O(1)` amortized time complexity

Comment: shouldnt the line `stack1.push(stack2.pop())` be `stack2.push(stack1.pop())`? you want to get all elements from `stack1` into `stack2`...

Answer (score 1):

Both LIFO and FIFO can be implemented with an array, the only difference between them is in the way *tail* and *head* pointers work. Given you start with LIFO, you can add two extra pointers that would reflect FIFO's tail and head, and then add methods to Add, Remove an so on using the FIFO pointers.

The output type would be as fast as a dedicated FIFO or LIFO type, however it would support both. You would need to use distinctive type members, like AddToStack/AddToQueue, RemoveFromStack/RemoveFromQueue etc.

Comment: Actually, pointers can't solve everything. Here we are in the idea of a simple LIFO, let's say a stack. You only have push() and pop() method on it. Neither you can access the inside things of the LIFO, nor you can use pointer because when popping the front of the FIFO wrapper, how will you shift everything to the front of the LIFO ?

Comment: This answer assumes that you have direct access to the structure and you can modify it. In this way you will be able to add extra pointers and extra methods. There is nothing in your question saying that one cannot modify LIFO structure.

Comment: I see. Indeed the question was not "how to transform a LIFO into a FIFO" but really "how to IMPLEMENT fifo USING lifo". I was not clear enough it seems. But if I had access to the inner things, I would basicly just change the lifo into a fifo, of course... !